# MS RDP client minimum iOS version on Apple iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, remote-desktop, compatibility, microsoft

Kinda new to Apple world so need some clarification here: does official MS RDP client support older iPads or no?

[On the official app page](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id714464092?mt=8) they say that minimum required iOS version is 8.0, but in these [Getting Started docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-ios) they state that iOS 6 is supported too. So I'm a bit confused with what to believe?

Will I be able to use RDP client on older iPads with iOS 4 or iOS 5?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Microsoft software is not written by Apple.

Comment: @IconDaemon A lot of questions on this site are about software not written by Apple actually

Comment: We can't answer questions about implementation details. As for "will I be able to use it: Have you tried?

Comment: The answer to the question is: (A) No, the desktop operating system for Macs is called macOS - it is not the same as iOS, and as such, no confusion can be made there. (B) The App Store page lists the minimum compatible iOS version for the current version of the app. The docs might refer to an older version of the app. (C) Using the device with the old iOS version, you will be able to download an older version of the app that supports your iOS _if_ (and only if) the developer made it available. (D) You can use an RDP client from others than Microsoft, if they haven't made it available.

Comment: @jksoegaard, thx for the answer. `if (and only if) the developer made it available`: how to check that in advance? without buying the device with that iOS

Comment: @Suncatcher As far as I know, there's no way to check in advance, except perhaps asking someone else who has an old device to check. However, why in the world are you purchasing iPads today that only work with iOS 5? - This must be the original, first generation iPad you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would trust the Apple reviewers that iOS 8.0 is the minimum required.

Also, I would also plan on not buying any hardware that is 32 bit since we’re so close to iOS 11 and no more 32 bit apps.

Microsoft’s support is actually pretty amazing for iOS - so you could ask them if they plan on leaving older versions of the app available. Developers don’t have to take down all downloads when they remove an app version from sale. So you could buy the app “for free” now and then ride an iOS 8 or iOS 6 device for years by backing up the older app version to iTunes and/or counting on it being available for “legacy download”.

There’s no guarantee they keep the old version up, so you should plan on iTunes and buying new hardware if you are riding the “about to be obsoleted” line for used / older iOS hardware and versions.

Comment: I agree and can attest that Microsoft's support for Apple has been very good (quite excellent, actually) in recent years.  MS will keep/kill the App depending on it's popularity.  That said, they have been quite consistent with keeping the App available but not continuing development.